# Regex substitution for zero decimal currency

Tags: c#, regex, formatting, currency

I need to format input *currency* (with no decimal places) to standard way (like `$XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX`).
User can input *any* of below:

1. `$123`
2. `$123,123`
3. `$1,123,123`
4. `123,123`
5. `12,123,123`
6. `12312312`
7. `123`
8. `$12123123`

I have written a `Regex` through which i can find the pattern needed --> `^\$?[0-9]{1,3}(?:(,[0-9]{3})*|([0-9]{3})*)?$` but I am not able to understand how to write *substitute* in order to *format* above examples to `$XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX...` format (as there are *no fixed groups* which I can pick).

Comment: easy to do it via string manipulation rather than regex

Comment: Remove comma, remove dolar parse as int use format `C` (for currency.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of *regular expressions* I suggest *parsing* and *formatting*:

```
  Func<string, string> beautify = (value) => decimal
    .Parse(value,                                        // parse initial value as
           NumberStyles.Currency,                        // currency
           CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))          // of the US
    .ToString("c0",                                      // format as currency (no cents)
               CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));     // of the US
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "$123",
    "$123,123",
    "$1,123,123",
    "123,123",
    "12,123,123",
    "12312312",
    "123",
    "$12123123",
  };

  string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-15} -> {beautify(test)}"));

  Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
$123            -> $123
$123,123        -> $123,123
$1,123,123      -> $1,123,123
123,123         -> $123,123
12,123,123      -> $12,123,123
12312312        -> $12,312,312
123             -> $123
$12123123       -> $12,123,123
```

Comment: Interresting ! I came with a solution using `int.Parse(Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9]", ""));` to strip any non numeric character and then `String.Format("{0:n0}", num);` (but that works only for integers)

Comment: @Cid: Why should we reinvent the wheel when we let .net do its work (parsing and formatting)?
I doubt if we should strip *any non numeric character*; what if I have `"+7(999)55-777-888"` input (typical user error, he put phone number isntead of currency)? Let me have an *exception thrown* instead of being charged for *8 billion*